# Create a new column by regex match

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk

I have this data in a `. csv` file:

```
age,sex,bmi,smoker,region,charges
19,female,23.9,yes,southwest,16884.924
23,male,29.83,no,northeast,1725.5523
```

I would like to create a new column based on some patterns attending the third column (bmi).

```
desnutrition='^([^,]*,){3}[1][0-7].[0-9]*'
low='^([^,]*,){3}[1][8-9].[0-9]*'
normal='^([^,]*,){3}[2][0-4].[0-9]*'
high='^([^,]*,){3}[2][5-9].[0-9]*'
obesity='^([^,]*,){3}[3-4][0-9].*'
```

The desired output is:

```
age,sex,bmi,smoker,region,charges,bmi_level
19,female,23.9,yes,southwest,16884.924,normal
23,male,29.83,no,northeast,1725.5523,high
```

Is there any way able to do that (preferably using bash or awk)?

Comment: Using regexps for this is extremely unlikely to be the best approach. Please [edit] your question to state your requirements in terms of numbers and arithmetic to be performed on the values in the `bmi` column instead of regexps across the whole line.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your regexps correctly, I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
NR == 1 {
    level = "bmi_level"
}
NR > 1 {
    bmi = $3
    if      ( bmi >= 30 ) { level = "obese" }
    else if ( bmi >= 25 ) { level = "high" }
    else if ( bmi >= 20 ) { level = "normal" }
    else if ( bmi >= 18 ) { level = "low" }
    else                  { level = "desnutrition" }
}
{ print $0, level }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
age,sex,bmi,smoker,region,charges,bmi_level
19,female,23.9,yes,southwest,16884.924,normal
23,male,29.83,no,northeast,1725.5523,high
```

If that's not exactly right hopefully it's obvious how to tweak the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

regex seems wrong

- `^([^,]*,){3}` would refer to first three field, and you need only first two.

I am unsure even `^([^,]*,){2}` would do what you expect.

using you data, and the line for normal

- `sed -n -e '/^([^,]*,){2}[2][0-4].[0-9]*/p' data.csv` yield no result
- `sed -n -e '/^[^,]*,[^,]*,[2][0-4].[0-9]*/p' data.csv` find proper line.

So I rewrote your regex

```
desnutrition=^[^,]*,[^,]*,[1][0-7].[0-9]*
low=^[^,]*,[^,]*,[1][8-9].[0-9]*
normal=^[^,]*,[^,]*,[2][0-4].[0-9]*
high=^[^,]*,[^,]*,[2][5-9].[0-9]*
obesity=^[^,]*,[^,]*,[3-4][0-9].*
```

You turn thoses regex in a sed script using awk

```
awk -F= '{ printf "/%s/s/^.*$/&,%s/\n",$2,$1 ;}' range2.lst
/^[^,]*,[^,]*,[1][0-7].[0-9]*/s/^.*$/&,desnutrition/
/^[^,]*,[^,]*,[1][8-9].[0-9]*/s/^.*$/&,low/
/^[^,]*,[^,]*,[2][0-4].[0-9]*/s/^.*$/&,normal/
/^[^,]*,[^,]*,[2][5-9].[0-9]*/s/^.*$/&,high/
/^[^,]*,[^,]*,[3-4][0-9].*/s/^.*$/&,obesity/
```

then you feed sed script to `sed`

```
awk -F= '{ printf "/%s/s/^.*$/&,%s/\n",$2,$1 ;}' range2.lst | sed -f - data.csv
age,sex,bmi,smoker,region,charges
19,female,23.9,yes,southwest,16884.924,normal
23,male,29.83,no,northeast,1725.5523,high
```

I do not gave details either of `awk` or generated `sed` commands purposefully as, unless doing this for fun or tutorial, I would recommand Ed Morton more straightforward's answer